# How should I find out the value of $f(t)$ in this question?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

> Let $f$:$[0,1]\mapsto[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $(f(t))^2<1+2\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds$, for all $t\in[0,1]$. Then which of the following is true:
>
> $a)$ $f(t)=1+t$  $\forall t\in[0,1]$
>
> $b)$ $f(t)<1+t/2$ $\forall t\in[0,1]$
>
> $c)$ $f(t)> 1+t$ $\forall t\in [0,1]$
>
> $d)$ $f(t)<1+t$ $\forall t\in [0,1]$
>
> IIT Joint Entrance Examination for M.Sc in 2021 , Single correct

I am having a hard time trying to find the correct answer. I tried differentiating it with respect to t using Leibnitz rule but all the information it gave me was that $f'(t)<1$. I have no idea how to tackle this problem, so any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $g(t) = \int_0^t f(s) ds$, then $g'(t) = f(t)$ and

$$g'(t) < \sqrt{1+ 2 g(t)}.$$
Dividing $\sqrt{1+2g}$ on both sides and integrating from $0$ to $t$,

$$\sqrt{1+2g(t)}- 1 < t\Rightarrow 1+2g(t) < (1+t)^2.$$

So

$$f^2(t) < 1+ 2g(t) \le (1+t)^2 \Rightarrow f(t) < 1+t. $$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a less than or equal to? $f(t) = 1+t$ worked when I put in the Q

Comment: @Buraian. It does not. If $f=1+t$ one has $f^2(t)=1+2\int_0^t f(s)ds$.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake in the calculations.